# store Ext.Ajax.request in variable and call success

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs3

Can I store Ext.Ajax.request in variable and call success as function.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
   success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      console.dir(obj);
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});
```

I want the above to to like this .

```
var ajax=  Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json'
    });

ajax.success(function(){});
```

when i call this function console log error Success is not function.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: i want to use same Ext.Ajax.request() function with different success function